# How do I find out in what revision a file got deleted?

Tags: svn, version-control

A file got deleted somewhere in my last 50 commits. Since the file is no longer being versioned, I can't just easily reference it. How do I check in my last 50 commits if and who deleted the file?

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy using Subversion 1.8+ command-line client. If you remember the name (part of the name will work as well) or some part of the path of the removed file, you can run [`svn log https://svn.example.com/svn/MyRepo --verbose --search FILENAME`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) to locate the revision which touched the file.

You can also use a grapchical client. For example, TortoiseSVN [is great at searching repository history](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html#tsvn-dug-showlog-filter).

Answer (score 0):

```
svn log file_that_was_deleted.txt
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It tells me that the file is not under version control.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
svn log -v -l 100 URL >result.lst
```

Take a look into that file...and use a find command via an editor than you know in which revision and who deleted that file.

May be on Windows you can use TortoiseSVN to do so..